# TS2345 error when a key in object args is written like [someKey]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsc, ts-loader

When

```
function StyleMixin(base: React.CSSProperties) {}




StyleMixin({
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    lineHeight: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    [someVariable]: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
    }
}
```

In `[someVariable]`, it says

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ fontWeight: "bold"; lineHeight: number;
>   textAlign: "center"; ...' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'CSSProperties'.   Object literal may
>   only specify known properties, and '[someVariable]' does not
>   exist in type 'CSSProperties'.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This happens if `someVariable` is a string literal type that is not a property of `React.CSSProperties`

```
const someVariable = "nonExistentProperty";
StyleMixin({
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    lineHeight: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    [someVariable]: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
    }
})
```

It will actually work if `someVariable` is a variable not a constant (ie. declared with `let` or `var`).

I suggest making sure you actually want to add a property not in `CSSProperties` (if you are not seeing the full error message use `"noErrorTruncation": true` in tsconfig.json)

If you actually want `StyleMixin` to be an object that can add extra properties to `CSSProperties` you can use a generic parameter in the function:

```
function StyleMixin< T extends React.CSSProperties>(base: T) {}
const someVariable = "nonExistentProperty";
StyleMixin({
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    lineHeight: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    [someVariable]: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
    }
})
```